# Type declaration works for object literal, but not for class implementation

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I want a type to represent a coordinate. The type I have have applied to an interface works for an object but not a class.

```
type ICoord = [number, number]

type MyInterface = {
    a: ICoord
}

var obj: MyInterface = { // works
    a: [0, 0]
}

class C implements MyInterface { // gets below compilation error
    a = [0, 0]
}
```

> `Property 'a' in type 'C' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'MyInterface'.
>     Type 'number[]' is missing the following properties from type '[number, number]': 0, 1`

#### Why can't I assign `[0, 0]` to `a`?

[[TypeScript Playground]](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/AQ4FwTwBwU2BJAwge2QJwCbALzANoB2ArgLYBGMaANMMeZQLoBQowLokswAshPAWEoAzAIYBjOLgDe7ViBEAuBCnQZZwAL7r1ANxFpgyMgCslvfoLSiJOYFOAB6B8ADu6ANYBnda0X4ADDT+zKxarOpiADYinp7AiMAAliRQkTAkMAJx5gLC4nD2TsAA5jBgcRSRyC7AYsgpidFgicgEwJRo6D6gIrZ4gcDB6lpAA)

Answer (score 2):

The type of `a` is being inferred as `number[]` which is not assignable to the tuple `[number, number]`. Explicitly defining the type as `ICoord` for `a` appears to work:

```js
type ICoord = [number, number];

type MyInterface = {
  a: ICoord;
}

class C implements MyInterface {
  a: ICoord = [0, 0];
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgwgewQJwCZQLxQNoDsCuAtgEYTIA0UBJZAugNwBQjokUAsiDLsGQGYBDAMbQsAb0ZQoAgFyxEKVEwC+TRgDcByKAmIArOZ269kgkZigSpAemtQA7igDWAZ0nS52AAyUvtRqrMQgA2Ai4uUHBQAJaEYMEQhBA8EUY8-MLQVlC2UADmEMARpMEI9lBCCHHRocDRCLhQZMgo7rLySGgW3r4MAYxAA)

Comment: While true, I'm sure the OP would like to know why the inference was handled properly in the object literal, but not in the class.

Comment: It seems odd/redundant that I need to indicate `a` should be of type `ICoord` in two places.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with contextual typing.

Typescript usses the expected type of an expression (`MyInterface` in this case) to make better inferences about object literals (also about function parameters). This is why assigning an object literal works well and the array literals is typed as a tuple type.

For classes things are a bit different. The `implements` clause is just used to check that the class correctly implements the interface AFTER the class has been independently typed. The `implements` keyword does not create any contextual typing for any of the class members. This is also the reason you have to specify function parameters types even if they would be obvious from the interface or base class.

Comment: So what is the correct way to type this so the class will not get this error. Skovy’s solution seems redundant. Why use the interface at all if I just have to tell the class again what the data type is for `a`.

Comment: Relevant GitHub issue asking for this feature: [microsoft/TypeScript#1373](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1373), closed as Won't Fix since the major attempt to implement it, [microsoft/TypeScript#6118](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6118), didn't go well (see [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6118#issuecomment-216595207))

Comment: @1252748 the correct way to do it is to specify the types again. The `implements` serves only as a check on the class.